# Fix all 'Naming rule violation' shown in VS2017 for all opened files at once

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, naming-conventions

Is there any tool witch allows to apply fix for all VS2017 messages like "*IDE1006  Naming rule violation: These words must begin with upper case characters*"?

In VS2017 it has to be done manually one by one, it shouldn't be hard to add such feature in IDE since all elements are listed.
I tried to find solution in Resharper but despite of its vast functionallity in matter of naming styles I didn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution. Resharper allows you to create custom naming rules in Options/CodeEditing/C#/NamingStyle go to Advenced Settings and add your custom rule.
In my case I wanted to fix lowercase event names to Uppercase.
I failed before because even though i selected UpperCamelCase_UndescoreTollerant for events Resharper didn't find any naming violations after CleanUp Code.

To make CleanUp Code find it one more thing is needed to be done.

The field Event subscriptions on fields is by default **$object$*$event$***, but it has to be changed to ***$:Luobject$$event$*** (:Lu - Regex First Character Uppercase)

Resharper after CleanUp Code allows you to fix naming by select event, click the light bulb and apply for a document/project/solution.

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWoAL.png)